# ¿Como puedo serializar un objeto a XML en donde sus metodos sean atributos de un XML en WCF?

Tags: .net, webservice, wcf

Quiero serializar o hacer que un Web service SOAP utilizando Microsoft WCF acepte y me muestre un XML en donde en vez de que cree o muestre un nodo por cada dato por ingresar me muestre como un atributo de xml.

Ejemplo:

```xml
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:wsar="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Models">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <tem:FacturaCompra>
             <!--Optional:-->
             <tem:compras>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <wsar:compras>
                   <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                   <wsar:Compra>
                      <!--Optional:-->
                      <wsar:adicional1>1</wsar:adicional1>
                      <!--Optional:-->
                      <wsar:adicional2>2</wsar:adicional2>
                      <!--Optional:-->
                      <wsar:adicional3>3</wsar:adicional3>
                   </wsar:Compra>
                </wsar:compras>
             </tem:compras>
             <!--Optional:-->
             <tem:cliente>1</tem:cliente>
          </tem:FacturaCompra>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Y se requiere de esta forma:

```xml
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:wsar="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Models">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <tem:FacturaCompra>
             <!--Optional:-->
             <tem:compras>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <wsar:compras>
                   <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                   <wsar:Compra adicional1="1" adicional2="2" adicional3="3"/>
                </wsar:compras>
             </tem:compras>
             <!--Optional:-->
             <tem:cliente>1</tem:cliente>
          </tem:FacturaCompra>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: WCF no soporta ese tipo de serialización. Puedes usar [XmlAttribute](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/xml-serialization-with-xml-web-services) con un web service asmx.